# Is there a way to Fetch API URI in Xamarin Forms?

Tags: c#, api, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am trying to create a mobile app and I am calling API.

```
 public async Task GetJsonAsync()
        {
            var uri = new Uri("http://192.168.254.114/api/connection.php");
            HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();
            var response = await httpClient.GetAsync(uri);
   ......
```

What I have done is set this emulator to its proxy address but still no success on displaying the data:

[image]

Comment: Try to enable "Use Andriod studio Http Proxy settings" in the image you showed. then use this to call the local api " http:// 10.0.2.2:PortNumber/api/connection.php"

Comment: Should I just check it and remove the ip address and port number? I am quite confuse because your suggestion gives me the same result even. What port number should I add to the code sir?

Comment: first enable No Proxy then enable "Use Andriod studio Http Proxy settings". After that get the local port your Api project is running on and replace it here  " http:// 10.0.2.2:PortNumber/api/connection.php"

Comment: Amjad - I'll let you know once I have done it

Comment: @AmjadS. just a quick question, how should I know my proper `port number` ? is it 80 then? or 3306 in my xampp?

Comment: @AmjadS. so I will not remove the Host name `192.168.254.114` and Port Number `80`?

Comment: the port is 3306. http:// 10.0.2.2:3306/api/connection.php

Comment: Whether the address of the virtual machine can be accessed normally?

Comment: @WenxuLi-MSFT can you help me on this? the api still cannot be fetched

Comment: Try to access the address in the browser address to see if the access is successful, if not, it is the address problem.